# Typescript add overload signature in derived class without new implementation

Tags: typescript, overloading

I'm looking to add an overload to a method from a derived class, using the same implementation.

```
class A {
    method(type: string, data: any): boolean {
        //implementation
    }
}

class B extends A {
    method(type: string, data: B): boolean;
}
```

Typescript gives me an error though since the method does no have an implementation. How can I add the overload without adding an implementation in the derived class?

Comment: What's the point of that overload?  Surely something that accepts `any` would also accept `B`.  Or are you saying you want `new B().method("abc", 123)` to be *rejected*?  You can probably get the behavior you want with interface merging but I'm very confused about what you're trying to do.  Could you please [edit] to make it obvious why someone would want this (e.g., change `any` to something incompatible with `B`, and also show use cases of calling `A` and `B`'s `method` where the overload is obviously useful)?

Comment: Are you trying to *override with less broad type*? That's impossible, as B instance must be assignable to A instance. If A.method can accept `any`, B.methot must too

Comment: You can use `method(type, data){ return super.method(type, data) }` to call A's method